# TypeError: undefined is not an object(evaluating events[0].name)

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

Why can't I access the state that I've already set inside the then block? events[0].name is the one causing this error. How do I pass data to my Timeline component to handle this asynchronous-ness?

```
  const Finalized = (props) => {
  const [events, setEvents] = React.useState([]);


  React.useEffect(() => {
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref("events/adventure")
      .once("value")
      .then((snapshot) => {
        setEvents(snapshot.val());
        // Not sure why when i console.log(events[0].name) my terminal gets flooded with the output
      });
  });
  let data = [
    {
      time: "09:00",
      title: "Event 1",
      description: <Text>{events[0].name}</Text>,
    },
  ];
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Timeline style={styles.list} data={data} />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the events in an asynchronous but trying to access events[0].name in the data array.
So in the initial render until the events are loaded you will get this error.

One fix you can do is to set description conditionally
 description: {events[0]?.name},

Or render the Timeline only if the events array has at least one element

```
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
     { events.length===1&& <Timeline style={styles.list} data={data} /> }
    </View>
  );
```

Better do a console log of your snapshot.val() to check the values you get from firebase too.

Comment: Thanks, your second suggestion worked but I don't really get what your first suggestion means by {events[0]?.name} can you explain it to me?

Comment: in the data array if you set the description like that it will send an empty description, second one is the better option actually :)

Comment: Does the events array has items when the error occurs ?

Comment: applying the second suggestion only I would still get the error when I first start up the app. Combining the first and second suggestion from you did the trick

Comment: oh oki, better check the events array contents :)